# I want to repeat some lines of code if user inputs wrong value

Tags: c#

I am sorry if this question was  asked many times, I searched for answer, but could not find one that had answer in C# language. My code has several issues. (I could also use switch bock down there, but I am required to use if blocks). Problem is, that if user enters e.g. "a" for operation, program keeps going until reaches the end and outputs that there was an error in input. So I want to give user "second chance" to enter a correct operation or number(Program also exits if user input invalid input in number tab) in input and my program to repeat questions until user enters correct one.Hope you understand. Thanks.

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
  {
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       while(true)
       {

       double num1;
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
       string number1 =  Console.ReadLine();
       if (double.TryParse(number1, out num1)) 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("First number is " + num1);
       } else if(number1.ToLower() == "quit")
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Goodbye...");
          break;
       } else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("That is not a number");
          break;

       }
       //Prompt the user for an operation (+ - / *).

       Console.Write("Enter an operation: ");
       string operation = Console.ReadLine();
          if(operation.ToLower() == "quit")
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Goodbye...");

          }

       double num2;
       Console.Write("Enter second number: ");
       string number2 = Console.ReadLine();
       if(double.TryParse(number2, out num2))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Second number is " + num2);

       } else if(number2.ToLower() == "quit")
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Goodbye...");
          break;
       } else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("That is not a number");

       }

       if(operation == "+")
       {
           Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);       
       } else if(operation == "-")
       {
           Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
       } else if(operation == "*")
       {
           Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
       } else if(operation == "/")
       {
           Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
       } else if(operation == "^")
       {
           Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(num1, num2));
       } else 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("---------------------\nSomething went 
          wrong,\nplease check your input and try again");
       }

       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to learning to code - best way is to write down how you as a human would do it, so, if I enter A for a number, you have a test to see if its not a number so you're almost there, how do you think you should tell it to go back and get another input

Comment: if its in another language, search for a code converter (:

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try it out.

Comment: "*I could also use switch bock down there, but I am required to use if blocks...*" Either is a homework assignment or you have a big problem.

Comment: It is exercise in which I had to use only if blocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the semantic logic of what you're trying to express:

> While the input is not parsed as a number, prompt for input.

Does this logic use some terminology similar to some keywords in C#?  This describes a loop which would repeatedly prompt the user for input until that input can be parsed as a number.  For example, a simple version might look something like this:

```
double num1;
string number1;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    number1 = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!double.TryParse(number1, out num1);
```

You could add more logic which might present a message to the user to tell them that it wasn't a number and they should try again.  You could add more logic which limits the number of attempts before giving up on the user.  Etc.

But basically any time you have some action which you want to repeat until some logical condition is met, what you want is a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is why you were blocked, but everywhere in your code you used ['break'](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) which will exit your while loop.

Given your code, if you want to continue to the next loop iteration if user does not input a number, you should use a '[continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue)'

I hope that helps ;)

**EDIT:** PS:  I strongly suggest you follow the above comments to have a better code flow :) Good luck !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will check those comments too :)